# Proof of nested interval theorem from bolzano weiertress theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I am able to proof bolzano weiertress theorem from nested interval theorem but can I do the reverse part?

Comment: State your problem more clearly.

Comment: I wanna prove the nested interval theorem from bolzano weiertress theorem.

Comment: Is the nested interval theorem the following : any sequence of nested closed and bounded intervals has non-empty intersection? Just to clarify,

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг As this is for real analysis, the claim is probably "nested closed, bounded intervals **whose lengths tend to zero** ...", and then the claim is "have one unique point at their intersection" (this in fact is known as Cantor's Lemma)

Comment: No it is not that. Bolzano says that The theorem states that each bounded sequence in Rn has a convergent subsequence. From which we have to prove the nested interval theorem

Comment: Please state the nested interval theorem, or verify what has been said above.

Comment: Yes it is that which is said above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can suppose you have $I_1=[\alpha_1,\beta_1]\supset I_2=[\alpha_2,\beta_2] \supset ... \supset I_n=[\alpha_n,\beta_n] \supset ...$

Then take the sequence $\alpha_1 \leq \alpha_n \leq b_1$ which is bounded , from B-W there is a subsequene $\alpha_{k_{n}} \to \alpha $ and show now that this $\alpha$ belongs to $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$.

Set $n \in \Bbb N$ , then for $m\geq n$ you have $k_{m}\geq k_{n} \geq n$. So $\alpha_n \leq \alpha_{k_{m}} \leq \beta_{k_{m}} \leq \beta_n$. So if you take $m\to \infty $ you get $\alpha_n\leq \alpha \leq \beta_n$ which means that $\alpha \in [\alpha_n,\beta_n]$.

Comment: How can I show that $a$ belongs to the intersection?

Comment: i edited the above

Comment: Wow that's cool.I got you.Many thanks

Comment: Can you just say that m tends to infinity?

Comment: you mean to take the $\alpha_m$ term instead of $\alpha_{k_{m}}$? If this is the case you cant do this because you dont know in advance if the $\alpha_m$ term is a term of your subsequence that you are given from BW.

Comment: No.. not like that.. I wanted to know that if we can say m tends to infinity without any proper proof.

Comment: i guess you agree that i showed that for every $m \geq n$ we have $\alpha_n \leq \alpha_{k_{m}} \leq \beta_{k_{m}} \leq \beta_n$. Now we can get limits.Its the same situtation when you having something like this $\alpha <\gamma_n < \beta$ for all $n>n_0$ and you take limits (if the limit of $\gamma_n $exists) $\alpha\leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \gamma_n \leq \beta.$ but now our $n$ is $m$.